# Clear form if DIV is closed

Tags: javascript

I want to clear my form if the DIV closed by itself (timer).

```
function openForm() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";

    startTimer();
}

var timer;
function startTimer() {
    timer = setTimeout(hideDiv, 60000); 
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", stopTimer, false);

function hideDiv() {
    document.getElementById('myForm').reset(); 
    //$("#client")[0].reset();
    document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
}

function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'block';
}

function stopTimer() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    startTimer();
    showDiv();
}

startTimer();
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
    <form name="form"  class="form-container" method="post" onsubmit="return doValidate()">
        <h1 align="center">Reservierung erstellen</h1>

            <label><b>Organisator:</b><br> <input placeholder="Name (Max Mustermann)" id="name" list="users" name="mitarbeiter" required /></label>
            <datalist id="users" class="dle" > <!-- autocomplete="off" -->
                <?php
                    for ($i=0; $i<$counts; $i++) {
                        echo '<option value="'.$AllData[$i]["mail"][0].'">'.$AllData[$i]["cn"][0].'</option>';
                    }
                ?>
            </datalist>
        <label for="psw"><br><br><b>Zeit der Reservierung:</b></label><br>
        von <input type="time" name="zeitstart"> Uhr bis <input type="time" name="zeitende"> Uhr <br><br>

        <!-- <input type="submit" class="btn" name="submit" value="Reservierung erstellen" /> -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn" name="submit">Reservierung erstellen</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn cancel" onclick="hideDiv()">Abbrechen</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

The command should by in "hideDiv()" right?
I tried it with "document.getElementById('myForm').reset();" but it dont worked.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is `myForm` actually the ID of the `form` element? Or of the `div` you are talking about? This lacks necessary info, please read [mcve].

Comment: Please post the HTML of your form so we have a better understanding

Comment: Yes please post html also

Comment: Im sorry, I added the html part. :)

Comment: As I suspected, `myForm` is the ID of your `div` element. You need to call the `reset` method on the `form` element.

Comment: @04FS oh its not. it was the ID from the div.

Comment: @04FS Yes, u right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try getting the child input elements of the form and setting their value to ''.

```
var inputs = document.getElementById("myForm").getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].value = '';
}
```

Comment: This is a workaround but isn't actually resetting the form. The `reset()` function in javascript will reset the form to it's default values - so if the default value was not `null` or `empty` then this isn't performing to what the OP has asked.